# How to splice a wire to this tiny pin on vibration sensor switch?

Tags: sensor

[image: Vibration Sensor]

I purchased this vibration sensor on Adafruit (PN: SW-18010P). Its pretty simple, when you tap it, an internal spring makes contact with the straight middle pin and closes the circuit. I need to install this and somehow wire these back to my IO system. Is there a proper way to splice into the smaller pin on the top. For estimation, it looks like a single strand of 22AWG wire so it is quite thin and I don't want to break it. Any tips would be great!

Comment: I have a feeling that if I post "You solder it down to a prototype board" you are going to comment "Oh I forgot to mention I don't have a soldering iron".

Comment: (Also, that's a stupid design for a product that is _designed_ to be used in a potentially high vibration environment!)

Answer (score 2):

A [manufacturer](https://soldered.com/productdata/2016/02/Soldered_SW-18020_datasheet.pdf) just shows them soldered into a PCB along with a lot of tortured English. The thicker pin provides the support. In both cases, but particularly in the lay-down orientation you might want to add some adhesive between the case and the PCB to keep the wires from flexing and eventually breaking.

[image]

You could just solder it into a [prototyping PCB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078W1F3PC) (cut it to a shorter length if you want) and run some wires to a 0.1" pitch header to plug into your protoboard.

[image]

Alternatively you could splice the wires directly with shrink tubing over the wires (and a third piece over the body to keep the wires from bending too close to the body, and to hold the two wires together). Using fine stranded wire will make the job easier. You could use AWG30 wire-wrap wire but it won't stand up will to repeated bending. Don't attempt to splice to thick wire directly.

Note: If the Adafruit model is like the datasheet, it does not appear to be very resistant to soldering heat (2 ~ 2.5 seconds at 280°C). So work quickly and leave reasonably long leads. If you can heat sink the lead between the joint and sensor (with a small vise jaw, a hemostat, needle nose pliers etc) all the better.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get some microwire strippers as they drastically reduce the chance of damaging the wire (a nick will case stress concentration). I use [these](https://www.knipex.com/en-uk/products/wire-strippers-and-stripping-tools/mini-wire-strippers/mini-wire-strippers/1280040SB) with good results, but there are several good designs. Key is to be adjustable for the wire size in question.
2. Strip and tin the wires on the sensor and the extension wires.
3. Fix the sensor, and your extension wire to your mounting plate, to ensure there is no vibration stress on the joint/wire (cyanoacrylate+activator is great for tacking).
4. Make the solder joints.